# regexp replace '1x' and '1x²' with 'x' and 'x²' (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace every '1x' and '1x²' in a mathematical string with 'x' and 'x²' :

```
var str = '1x² + (1x − 11x)(1x² + 1x²)'; //string to be parsed
var reg = str.replace(/1x/g, 'x');
console.log(reg);
```

Problem is my regexp also matches numbers like '11x' or '21x', which is obviously not what I want. So my code currently outputs `x² + (x − 1x)(x² + x²)` instead of `x² + (x − 11x)(x² + x²)`.

I know why I get this behaviour, but I don't know how to fix it. How can I get my regexp to match every 1x and 1x² if and only if they are not preceded by another number like '11x' or 221x²' ?

Comment: Use a word boundary? `str.replace(/\b1x\b/g, 'x');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) with regex to avoid matching `1x` within `11x`.

```js
var str = '1x² + (1x − 11x)(1x² + 1x²)'; //string to be parsed
var reg = str.replace(/\b1x/g, 'x');
console.log(reg);
```

Comment: Your solution does exactly what I want and taught me a tool I will be using a lot in the future ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
var str = '1x² + (1x − 11x)(1x² + 1x²)'; //string to be parsed
var reg = str.replace(/(^|\D)1x(\D|$)/g,'$1x$2');
```